# Free WordPress form plugin with upload files option

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress and I should build a simple form with a option to upload files and send them to mail, but I need I free plugin to do that. Can somebody recommend me one?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use contact form7 and upload file attachment like below image:

Plugin url: https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

Form code:

[file your-file limit:2mb filetypes:doc|docx|jpg|jpeg|pdf]

File Attachments Code:

[your-file]

[image]